# Having Problems creating an if else statement to go to multiple pages based on the score of a quiz

Tags: javascript, html

I successfully created a tallied list that is scored and now I need to link the score to a specific next page or score page. there are 28 different score pages one fore each possible score. can some one please help me with the if else statements for this when I use what I think should be used it comes up completely wrong and errors out.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Toxic Test Quiz</title>




<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://fast.fonts.net/cssapi/731cabbe-df4e-4566-ac88-f64a4500c6b6.css"/>

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pathway+Gothic+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans:100,400,700,100italic,400italic,700italic"/>

<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript">
  function unhide(divID) {
    var item = document.getElementById(divID);
    if (item) {
      item.className=(item.className=='hidden')?'unhidden':'hidden';
    }
  }
</script>

</head>
<body>
<form>
   <table style="width: 880px;">
     <tr>
       <td>
            <input type=checkbox name=b1>Ammonium Hydroxide<br/><br>
        <input type=checkbox name=b3>2-Butoxyethanol<br/><br>
        <input type=checkbox name=b5>Di-(Palm Carboxyethyl)<br/><br>
        <input type=checkbox name=b7>Methoxydiglycol<br/><br>
        <input type=checkbox name=b9>Benzalkonium Chlorides<br/><br>
        <input type=checkbox name=b11>Phosphates<br/><br>
        <input type=checkbox name=b13>Silicon Compounds<br/><br>
            </td>


            <td>
            <input type=checkbox name=a1>Hydrozincite<br/><br>
        <input type=checkbox name=a3>Antifoam<br/><br>
        <input type=checkbox name=a5>Buffer<br/><br>
        <input type=checkbox name=a7>Glycol Ethers<br/><br>
        <input type=checkbox name=a9>Glutaral<br/><br>
        <input type=checkbox name=a11>Ethanolamine<br/><br>
        <input type=checkbox name=a13>Alumina<br/><br>
            </td>

            <td>
            <input type=checkbox name=a2>Polyacrylates<br/><br>
        <input type=checkbox name=a4>Polyethylene Glycol<br/><br>
        <input type=checkbox name=a6>Ethanolamine<br/><br>
        <input type=checkbox name=a8>Atrazine<br/><br>
        <input type=checkbox name=a10>Alcohol Ethoxylates <br/><br>
        <input type=checkbox name=a12>Petroleum<br/><br>
        <input type=checkbox name=a14>Polysorbate-20 <br/><br>
            </td>

            <td>
            <input type=checkbox name=b2>Sodium Tripolyphosphate<br/><br>
        <input type=checkbox name=b4>Myristalkonium Saccharinate<br/><br>
        <input type=checkbox name=b6>Alcohol Alkoxylates<br/><br>
        <input type=checkbox name=b8>Poloxamer 124 <br/><br>
        <input type=checkbox name=b10>Hexoxyethanol<br/><br>
        <input type=checkbox name=b12>Methylisothiazolinone<br/><br>
        <input type=checkbox name=b14>Triethanolamine<br/><br>
                                 </td>
                             </tr>
                           </table>

                           <input type=button onclick="doIt(this.form)" value="SUBMIT">


<BR>YOUR FINAL HOUSEHOLD TOXICITY SCORE: <input size=2 type=text name=clicked value=0 onfocus=blur()>
</form>

<script>
function doIt(_f)
{
    var _countCK=0;
    var _countTL=0;
    //get all the input types...new way
    var cboxarr = _f.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for(var i=0;i<cboxarr.length;i++)
    {
        //declare your _obj variable as the particular elements...rest the same
        var _obj = cboxarr[i];
        if(_obj.name!=undefined)
        {
          if(_obj.type=="checkbox")
          {
            _countTL++;
            if(_obj.checked)
              _countCK++;
          }
        }
    }
    _f.clicked.value=_countCK;
    _f.notclicked.value=0+_countTL-_countCK;
} 
</script>

                           if (_countCK===0){
            <a href="mommysclub.com/toxictest/results-0"><img style="float: right; margin: 0 150px 0 0;" src="images/nextbtnp1.png"></a>      
        }else (_countCK===1){
            <a href="mommysclub.com/toxictest/results-1"><img style="float: right; margin: 0 150px 0 0;" src="images/nextbtnp1.png"></a>      
        }else (_countCK===2){
            <a href="mommysclub.com/toxictest/results-2"><img style="float: right; margin: 0 150px 0 0;" src="images/nextbtnp1.png"></a>      
        }else (_countCK===3){
            <a href="mommysclub.com/toxictest/results-3"><img style="float: right; margin: 0 150px 0 0;" src="images/nextbtnp1.png"></a>      
        }else



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you trying to put an image there? And btw, you can just throw javascript out of the <script> tag

Comment: Hello, I need a button image to look at the _countck from the script and to direct it to the results page based on the score of the test. can you please help I am new to coding and I can't figure this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do the following, if your links only differs in "_countCK"

Add to the script section: 
(If you're using Jquery)

```
$("#myLink").prop("href", "mommysclub.com/toxictest/results-" + _countCK);
```

(If not)

```
document.getElementById("myLink").href= "mommysclub.com/toxictest/results-" + _countCK;
```

And for the HTML:

```
<a id="myLink" href="#"><img style="float: right; margin: 0 150px 0 0;" src="images/nextbtnp1.png"></a>
```

Comment: This didn't work and I am trying to show a next page button and make that button go to the results page based on the _countCK do you have another solutions?

Comment: Try using document.getElementById("myLink").href=mommysclub.com/toxictest/results-" + _countCK;

Comment: it is so close!!! ins tread of going to corresponding test page which they are names results-1.php and results-2.php ext it is just reloading the the test page again

Answer (score 1):

The structure of if else for your need should be like this.

```
if(_countCK===0){

}else if(_countCK===1){

}else if(_countCK===2){

}
```

You are doing something like this which is wrong

```
if (_countCK===0){

}else (_countCK===1){

}else (_countCK===2){

}
```

Comment: and it can have one "else" directive without any condition.

Comment: I understand but this docent seem to work it shows multiple images and it shows the code on the site instead of actually doing it. please help